# rails semantic ui jquery not updating field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui, pickadate

I've run into a strange problem where I can't get a date picker to update the field in a rails app. I've tried a few different date pickers, so it's not a problem with the jquery plugin. Same results.

There's nothing strange about what I'm trying to do.

```
<div class="datepicker field">
  <label>Date of Birth</label>
  <%= f.text_field :dob %>
</div>
```

I have tried both with manual turbolinks workarounds..

```
var ready;
ready = function() { .... everything in here }
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

and with jquery-turbolinks gem.  It always gives me the same result - the jquery will load the picker, but the field does not get updated.

I believe I've got it narrowed down to Semantic UI at this point, but I'm happy to  be proven wrong.

application.js :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require semantic-ui
//= require pickadate/picker 
//= require pickadate/picker.date 
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

relevant portion of local js:

```
$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').pickadate()
});
```

Any clues as to what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: Just seeing this, but for anyone who gets here, `//= require turbolinks` should be placed before `//= require semantic-ui`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, I figure out my problem 10 seconds after posting the question.

The answer is to attach the jquery right on the text_field, thusly:

```
<div class="field" >
  <label>Date of Birth</label>
  <%= f.text_field :dob, id: "datepicker" %>
</div>
```

Joy.